# Trying to run a service under Mono on OSX: Only MessageVersion.None is allowed for WebHttpBehavior

Tags: .net, macos, web-services, mono

I am trying to run one of my services written in .NET, compiled with Visual Studio 2015 SP3.

The service opens a number of endpoints listening to HTTP port 80 so for this reason I start it like this:

```
mono-service MyService.exe
```

It just quits so I am trying to debug the service using:

```
sudo mono --debug /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe MyService.exe
```

Now it outputs this into /var/log/system.log:

```
Jul 16 21:30:27 iMac mono[46084]: MyService.exe: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Jul 16 21:30:27 iMac mono[46084]: MyService.exe: Only MessageVersion.None is allowed for WebHttpBehavior
```

Which leads me to think that there is an issue with my endpoints in Mono.

This is pretty much how I open the endpoints in code:

```
interfaceCarpHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyInterface));
interfaceCarpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyInterface), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost/MyInterface");
interfaceCarpHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
interfaceCarpHost.Open();
```

Comment: Mono does not implement all bits of WCF. You should use ASP.NET Web API on Mono (which uses more Microsoft source code), or simply switch to ASP.NET Core on .NET Core which is purely Microsoft code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @LexLi maybe this is the way to go. Can you give me some instructions on how to switch the core so I can use it in mono?

Comment: By switching to .NET Core, you are free of Mono, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ Note that you must focus on ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET.

Comment: But I am writing a service. Can I use it then also?